Emulator MDM fully enrolled device
We have a project and development within an Esri ArcGIS enterprise platform that will utilise the FieldMaps Android (standard Play Store) application. We need to work out how to side-load data (regional map data) onto the device within an MDM-managed environment. However, we are struggling to use Android Studio to create a fully managed device within a mobile device management platform.
We have tried:

At AVD Creation, we don't get an option to allow the out-of-the-box experience (i.e. initially setup) to enroll a device into fully managed.

We have attempted to factory reset the emulated device but it never actually resets

We have been able to enroll a device as a work profile, but this isn't the same as a Managed Device.


For a fully managed Android device, you press the screen 8 times at the setup stage and it asks how you want to enroll, but in the emulator, it bypasses this.
Any way to get it back? Or is it a specific image we need or is it not possible?

Just don't use emulated devices. Only use physical devices.
